# MongoDB duplicate "_id " for an array "_id"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

Consider db "test" in my standalone mongodb instance.
I created a collection called testCol and inserted a document with the following syntax :

```
db.testCol.insert({_id:{"age":22,"empId":1},"DOJ":"22JUL"})
```

which results in :

**WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })**

and upon quering

```
db.testCol.find()
```

I get

**{ "_id" : { "age" : 22, "empId" : 1 }, "DOJ" : "22JUL" }**

However upon inserting another document with the same _id with different positioning of the array elements with syntax :

```
db.testCol.insert({_id:{"empId":1,"age":22},"DOJ":"22JUL"})
```

which results in :

**WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })**

and upon quering the collection using

```
db.testCol.find()
```

I get

**{ "_id" : { "age" : 22, "empId" : 1 }, "DOJ" : "22JUL" }**
**{ "_id" : { "empId" : 1, "age" : 22 }, "DOJ" : "22JUL" }**

Is this a bug because to query the document with the unique _id using the syntax :

```
db.testCol.find({"_id.age":22,"_id.empId":1})
```

will return

**{ "_id" : { "age" : 22, "empId" : 1 }, "DOJ" : "22JUL" }**
**{ "_id" : { "empId" : 1, "age" : 22 }, "DOJ" : "22JUL" }**

Why is this happening ? If mongodb follows a specific _id structure then shouldn't it return only 1 document from the final find command and if mongodb doesn't follow a specific structure then how does it let me insert multiple documents

Comment: Do I need to enable a specific configuration property; I'm using mongo 3.2.1 with the default configuration properties

Comment: Very good question. The JSON docs say that [an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs](http://www.json.org/), and it is [generally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up) [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051785/jsonobjects-keys-iterated-order) [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/json-object-property-order) the order of fields in a json object is not significant. And MongoDB say that [a document's _id must be unique](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/). So yes I think it's a bug, MongoDB is failing on its uniqueness check.

Answer (score 1):

I realised order matters to MongoDB when using an object as the value for a unique field such as the `_id` field.

Not sure if it can be termed a bug.

That said, with reference to your query:

```
db.testCol.find({"_id.age":22,"_id.empId":1})
```

what you are actually doing is querying based on individual components of the `_id` field and not the `_id` field as a whole.

You will be better served if your query targets the `_id` as a whole. This query should achieve what you intended.

```
db.testCol.find({"_id": {"age" : 22, "empId" : 1}})
```